# Strange behavior of `FourierSinCoefficient`

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, fourier-analysis

`FourierSinCoefficient` works normally like this and the result is checked with `Integrate`.

```
FourierSinCoefficient[Sin[2x], x, n]
(*  DiscreteDelta[-2 + n] *)

Integrate[2/Pi Sin[2x] Sin[2x], {x, 0, Pi}]
(*  1   *)
```

Q. Another try is in a stange behavior. I expect the following result is made with `ConditionalExpression` or `Piecewise` But that is `0` without `n`.

```
FourierSinCoefficient[(Sin[x] + Sin[2x]), x, n]
(*  0   *)
```

I think that's result might be `Piecewise[{{1, n == 1 || n == 2}, {0, True}}]`.

Contrastively, `FourierCoefficient` works normally like this.

```
FourierCoefficient[(Sin[x] + Sin[3 x]), x, n]

(* Piecewise[{{-I/2, n == 1 || n == 3},{I/2, n == -3 || n == -1}}, 0] *)
```

Comment: When I evaluate `Integrate[(2/Pi) Sin[2*x] Sin[n*x], {x, 0, Pi}]`, I get: $$\frac{4 \sin (\pi  n)}{\pi  \left(n^2-4\right)}$$. (Mathematica 10.0.2)

Comment: @Mahdi yes Q2 is my mistake:) sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this helps.
I think the problem can be traced back to this simple case.

Let

```
f[n_] := Sin[n \[Pi]]/(\[Pi] n)
```

This should `Simplify[]` to `DiscreteDelta[n].` But at least I have found no way to accomplish this.

Let us investigate the function.

For Mathematica `f[n]` it is zero for any integer because of the `Sin`:

```
Simplify[f[n], n \[Element] Integers]

(* Out[128]= 0 *)
```

The case `n==0` has slipped through.

For `n->0` we have

```
f[0]
```

> During evaluation of In[129]:= Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0
>   encountered. >>
>   During evaluation of In[129]:= Infinity::indet: Indeterminate
>   expression 0 ComplexInfinity encountered. >>

```
(* Out[129]= Indeterminate *)
```

So we have to take the limit

```
Limit[f[n], n -> 0]

(* Out[130]= 1 *)
```

Relevant in the present case is

```
c[n_, a_] = FourierSinCoefficient[Sin[a x], x, n]

(*
Out[146]= (2 (-1)^n n Sin[a \[Pi]])/(a^2 \[Pi] - n^2 \[Pi])
*)
```

For integers `a` and `n` this should `Simplify[]` to `DiscreteDelta[n-a].`
But again, it doesn't.

But the value is infact `DiscreteDelta[n-a]`

```
Table[{aa, 
   Limit[Table[{DiscreteDelta[n - aa], c[n, a]}, {n, 1, 3}], a -> aa]}, {aa, 1, 3}]

(* {
{1, {{1, 1}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}}}, 
{2, {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 0}}}, 
{3, {{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {1, 1}}}
} *)
```